# Why is the [[nodiscard]] attribute not transitive?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] float val() { return 3.; }
float junk() { return val(); }
int main() { junk(); }
```

It seems logical that `junk` should be required to be marked as `[[nodiscard]]`, yet the above example compiles without [any warnings](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4284e3adfb86ef4).

Put differently, what is the point of `val` being no discard, if its return value can be returned from a "discardable" function?

Comment: suppose `junk` would be `if (some_condition) return val(); else return 0.0;` Then `junk` correctly does not discard  `val`s return value, but that does not necessarily imply that `junk`s return value is non-discardable. You *can* specify `junk` as nodiscard, but it would be bad if it had to be

Comment: `[nodiscard]` only applies to the immediate caller i.e. your example is okay, since `junk()` does not discard the return value of `val()`.    In general cases, the compiler will not have visibility of the behaviour of `junk()` when compiling `main()` (e.g. if the definition of `junk()` and `main()` are in distinct source files) so cannot use logic of the form "`val()` is called by `junk()` so `main()` should not discard the return value of `junk()`".

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I get your point. I was more thinking along the lines of how `const` propagates over return types etc . (of course here we return a value, so a copy wouldn't cause troubles with const)

Comment: And what if `junk()` is void or returns something entirely different?

Comment: Or, what if `junk()` was something like `float junk() {some_static_variable = val();  return 42.0;}`.    That meets the requirement of not discarding the return value from `val()`, but there is no particular reason to suggest that `junk()` should automatically be `[nodiscard]`  (i.e. it is up to the person who writes `junk()`).

Comment: @Galik @Peter These are different cases .. I'm asking a different thing. But if I have to say what I expect, case 1 the return types cannot be chained so the return value cannot be discarded and case 2 the `val()` has not been discarded since it has been assigned to a variable and [[nodiscard]] cannot help you beyond that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[nodiscard]]` merely prevents the value returned from `val` to be discarded. `junk` is using the returned value so all is ok. If you want you can mark `junk` as `[[nodiscard]]`.

Moreover, note that there is no strong guarantee to get a warning in the first place ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard)):

> If a function declared nodiscard or a function returning an enumeration or class declared nodiscard by value is called from a discarded-value expression other than a cast to void, the compiler is **encouraged to issue a warning.**

The way to achieve the behavior you want is to use a custom class that is specified as `[[nodiscard]]`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct [[nodiscard]] foo {};

foo val() { return {};}
foo junk() { return val(); }

int main() {
    junk();
}
```

Gcc reports:

```
<source>:9:5: error: ignoring return value of function declared with 'nodiscard' attribute [-Werror,-Wunused-result]
    junk();
    ^~~~
```